# msxml3.dll error '80090326' from classic ASP script

Tags: msxml3

I have a classic asp script which has worked for years but which has just started to throw an error (following a Microsoft update on the 27th August).

The error is;

```
msxml3.dll error '80090326' 

The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.
```

The code generating the error is as follows;

```
Set objHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
Call objHTTP.setTimeouts(5000, 60000, 10000, 10000)
objHTTP.open "POST", url, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
objHTTP.send strPostdata
```

The error is generated by the last line.

The url is a secure site using "https://". The strPostData is a valid JSON string.

The script works fine from my development machine running Windows 7, but fails on the live server which is running Windows Server 2003 SP2.

Having researched this, a few old posts referring to this error suggest that using MSXML2.XMLHTTP instead of MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP has resolved the issue. However, when I try this, I get the error;

```
msxml3.dll error '800c0008' 

The download of the specified resource has failed.
```

I use exactly the same code in another script to access XML on another site which is not secure - just http:// - and that still works without a problem.

I have tried using msxml6.dll and get the same error.

On the server, if I browse to the secure site using the url in IE 7 I get the cannot display the page error. Chrome does display the page correctly, however.

The server does not have any SSL certificates installed.

Any suggestions would really help!

Comment: Further to my initial question, I have determined that this was NOT due to a Microsoft update but that the third party to which we are trying to connect have changed their security settings. They have limited the cipher suites they accept to a subest which is incompatible with those supported by Windows Server 2003. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa380512(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Confirmed: using `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0` in a Classic ASP environment, TLS/SSL negotiation errors like `80090326` occured, turning out the remote system required updates.